# ORA-00904: Invalid identifier when using forall

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert, ora-00904

When i run the following block, I get the error:

```
ORA-00904: Invalid identifier in "forall".
```

Can somebody please help me fix it?

The column "ID" is an 12c identity column, so number.

```
drop table t1 cascade constraints purge;

create table t1 (
  c1  number
);

set serveroutput on;

declare
  type l_t2 is table of number;
  l_c1 l_t2;
begin
  select ID
    bulk collect into l_c1
    from IDTABLE;

  dbms_output.put_line('Number of records: ' || sql%rowcount);

  forall i in l_c1.first..l_c1.last
    insert into t1 values l_c1(i);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing parentheses around the PL/SQL table reference in the values clause. Change this line:

```
    insert into t1 values l_c1(i);
```

to

```
    insert into t1 values (l_c1(i));
```

Without them it thinks `l_cl` is a schema-level object of some kind, which doesn't exist; hence the error you see. With them it works:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  type l_t2 is table of number;
  l_c1 l_t2;
begin
  select ID bulk collect into l_c1 from IDTABLE;
  dbms_output.put_line('Number of records: ' || sql%rowcount);
  forall i in l_c1.first..l_c1.last
    insert into t1 values (l_c1(i));
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Number of records: 2
```

Comment: oh god, you are right. i missed it. works now. thanks a lot!